How can I resolve the error 'TagInfo' was not declared in this scope?
I am working on an RFID project using the MFRC522 and Ethernet libraries. My code is encountering a compilation error, and I am not sure how to resolve it. Here is the specific error message:
Compilation error: 'TagInfo' was not declared in this scope
Below is the relevant part of my code:
`#include <SPI.h>
 #include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include "MFRC522Extended.h" // Include the extended library header

#define RST_PIN 9 // Reset pin for MFRC522
#define SS_PIN 10 // Slave Select pin for MFRC522

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Create MFRC522 instance

//Ethernet settings
byte mac[] = { 0x60, 0x3e, 0x5f, 0x86, 0xd8, 0xc9 }; // MAC address of Ethernet      shield
IPAddress server(127, 0, 0, 1); // IP address of your server (localhost)
int port = 3001; // Port number of your server

// Initialize the Ethernet client
EthernetClient client;

// Create an instance of MFRC522Extended
MFRC522Extended mfrc522Extended;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications
 SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
 mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522 module

// Initialize Ethernet with DHCP
if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
  Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
// Try with a static IP if DHCP fails:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, IPAddress(192, 168, 1, 177));
} else {
  Serial.print("Ethernet configured via DHCP, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

 Serial.println("RFID Ready");
}

void loop() {
  // Look for new RFID cards
  if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
  // Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.print("UID tag: ");
  String content = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
   Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
   Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
   content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
   content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  content.toUpperCase();
  Serial.println();

  // Perform extended functionality
  TagInfo tagInfo; // Declaration of TagInfo
  byte sendData[10]; // Example data
  byte backData[10]; // Example data
  byte sendLen = 10;
  byte backLen = 10;
  MFRC522::StatusCode status = mfrc522Extended.TCL_Transceive(&tagInfo, sendData,    sendLen, backData, &backLen);
if (status == MFRC522::StatusCode::SUCCESS) {
  // Process successful operation
  Serial.println("Extended operation successful");
} else {
  // Handle error
  Serial.println("Error in extended operation");
}

// Send UID to the server via Ethernet
if (client.connect(server, port)) {
  client.println("UID: " + content);
  // Optionally, send extended data as well
  // client.println("Extended Data: " + String(backData[0])); // Example
  client.stop();
}

delay(1000); // Delay for readability
}
}`

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can fix it?
This is code which I have tried for RFID where we used Arduino Uno R3 board, Ethernet shield W5100 and RFID reader MFRC522.Here I'm facing an issue with the connectivity, the expected output for the NodeJS server was to read the UID of the RFID card or tag but I'm getting an error of the tag info which I'm unable to solve, could you please assist me to solve the error.
Thank you

where do you think the type TagInfo should be declared?

I found online a header called MFRC522Extended.h which defines a MFRC522Extended::TagInfo. Do you mean that?

I have utilized this RFID library for my project, and the source file is :- https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/src/MFRC522Extended.h
This library is essential for managing and interfacing with RFID readers and tags, providing extended functionalities that are crucial for my implementation

TagInfo is nested inside MFRC522Extended. THe corrrect spelling is MFRC522Extended::TagInfo

Thank you for the clarification on MFRC522Extended::TagInfo. Your explanation really helped me understand how to properly reference it. I appreciate your assistance and everyone’s contributions in this thread. Have a great day!
